# Clean Install of Ubuntu won't boot [reboot and select proper boot device]

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu today. I deleted everything on my hard drive, and installed Ubuntu with efi-boot, swap, / and /home partition.

After installing and rebooting I just get the error message from the title and I have no idea why. I put my HDD in first place in the boot options.

All partitions show up fine in gparted too.

I installed 13.04 64-bit.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Well, first in the BIOS/UEFI settings, put USB and CD/DVD before the hard disk so you can use the live install media to boot and fix things.  What's your machine, each has its quirks.

Comment: @dochi - please click the contact us button at the bottom of this page and request that your two accounts are merged.  Then you'll be able to edit and maintain your own question.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Download and use this Ubuntu Boot-Repair program, or burn an Ubuntu boot-repair Disk**

I had the above problem installing Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04 on a brand new (as of November 2013) gateway computer and got this error:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device
```

I was able to repair the boot loader that caused this problem.

This Ubuntu boot-repair tool can repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu.  Or you can't boot Windows after installing a Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, or some software update or hardware upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Four options.  Either boot into the LiveCD and download the program and apply it to your boot loader, or create a Ubuntu OS install boot disk with boot-repair, or boot into a barebones boot-repair liveCD, or a boot repair USB stick.

What I did was boot into the Ubuntu LIVE CD and connected to the internet, then visit the following link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Follow the directions there to install the boot repair program and accept the defaults to rebuild and restore the boot loader.  For me accepting the defaults made it so I could boot into Ubuntu again.

Instead of downloading from a live CD, you could burn a boot Repair Disk which also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

LighterWeight (Lubuntu based) Boot-RepairCD: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Full Ubuntu 13.04 liveDVD or USB Install with Boot-Repair included (for newer computers): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxSecureRemix

For info on UEFI boot install & repair: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

So either pitch in and help the developers figure out why that version of Ubuntu isn't working with your hardware, or troubleshoot what is wrong by learning about how the boot process works, or try a different version of Ubuntu on a different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has EFI or UEFI firmware or has pre-installed Windows 8, you must choose Ubuntu 64-bit version. 32-bit version will not work.

Comment: As mentioned in the question I was using the 64bit version

Answer (score 0):

Get your priorities in order.... your boot option priorities that is.

After upgrading I saw 2 boot options in the bios marked "ubuntu (PO: ST9500420AS". I selected the 2nd one as the first boot disk and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today. For me the fix was to hit a different function key than the normal bios menu. This made a menu pop up that allowed me to select a device to boot from (this is also in BIOS, but this menu was a different thing that only allowed you to do that one thing). Then I selected the device "uefi: Ubuntu." This device was already selected as the first boot priority in my BIOS, but for some reason it didn't work until I used this second menu. I had used this menu before to boot from USB to install Ubuntu, so I'm thinking maybe this menu overrides what's in BIOS and it's persistent? I have no idea, but problem solved.