# After clean install of Ubuntu 14.04: "Reboot and select proper boot device". How do I fix this if Boot-Repair did not work?

Tags: boot, 14.04

I tried running Boot-Repair as referenced by the [following question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304144/clean-install-of-ubuntu-wont-boot-reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device), but after restarting, I still see the same "Reboot and select proper boot device" error.

Does anyone know another viable solution? I would prefer not to wipe the system again if possible because I thought Boot-Repair had fixed the problem and spent a lot of time setting up things. FYI, my machine is a new Acer Aspire. Also, from the live install USB, I executed "check disk for errors", which reported that there was one error, but didn't say what the error was. Additionally, at least one co-worker with an identical system has the same problem.

Update: I tried to boot off of a coworker's UEFI live USB, and this didn't work. I also noticed in the BIOS Setup Utility that the hard drive is listed as "[UEFI: ST1000DM003-1...]". Is this the issue? If so, how do I fix this?

Here is a link to ththe Boot-Repair output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7832746/

Comment: It was not an ideal solution, but disabling secure boot and csm in the bios and reinstalling the os seems to have fixed the problem, but I had to erase my data -- simply reinstalling the os did not work, even after changing the bios settings.